# Add http header in HTTPFound() with pyramid

Tags: http-headers, pyramid

I have a Pyramid application where I have the following line of code:

```
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('feeds'))
```

However I want to pass an extra parameter in the headers. Im trying with this:

```
headers = {"MyVariable": "MyValue"}
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('feeds'),headers=headers)
```

However the view_config of "feeds" does not get MyVariable in the headers. I'm checking it with the following code:

```
print "**************"
for key in request.headers.keys():
   print key
print "**************"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HTTP does not allow you to set headers and have them sent back by a client unless that client is specifically programmed to do so. The only way with HTTP to get data back from the client is by using the cookie mechanism.

Comment: @X-Istence: what *are* you talking about? One, the OP isn't even *mentioning* what header they are setting and why (it could be one of the standard headers) and b) extra headers are not necessarily aimed at transferring to specific clients. Not to mention that custom HTTP headers are perfectly normal and permitted in the HTTP RFCs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, you can set whatever headers you want. However the client (browser in this case) will not send those back on the next request to the browser after receiving the 303.

So user makes request: GET /
Server responds: 303 Found, Location: /whatever, X-My-Header: Whatever
Browser requests:
GET /whatever

X-My-Header doesn't get sent back to the server by the browser, even though it was set by the server on the reply.

Comment: @X-Istence: right, no, and I did miss that part.

Answer (score 1):

`headers` is meant to be a *sequence* of `(key, value)` pairs:

```
headers = [("MyVariable", "MyValue")]
```

This lets you specify a header more than once. Also see the [*Response* documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html?highlight=headerlist#response), the `headers` keyword is passed on as `headerlist` to the [`Response` object](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response) produced. Also see the [HTTP Exceptions documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/httpexceptions.html#http-exceptions):

> `headers`:
>   a list of (k,v) header pairs

However, headers are only sent to the client; they are *not* passed on by the client to the next request that they are instructed to make. Use `GET` query parameters if you need to pass information along to the redirection target, or set values in cookies or in the session instead.

To add on query parameters, specify a `_query` directory for `route_url()`:

```
params = {"MyVariable": "MyValue"}
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('feeds', _query=params))
```

and look for those query parameters in `request.GET`:

```
for key in request.GET:
    print key, request.GET.getall(key)
```

Comment: I tried this but still I don't get the variable "MyVariable". I just get Referer,User-Agent,Connection,Cookie,Host,Accept,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding

Comment: @QLands: are you 100% certain that you restarted your Pyramid server and are now running the new code? I'd have expected the old version to throw an exception, for example, since a dictionary is not a supported object, according to the documentation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What he wants to do is impossible with the HTTP standard unless he writes a custom client to do the work for him.

Comment: @X-Istence: I have no idea what you are going on about. Custom HTTP headers are perfectly normal and permitted in the HTTP standard. And what makes you assume this is about a custom HTTP header in the first place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Re-read the the question. Notice he sets headers and adds those to his `HTTPFound()` that he returns. Even if he fixes the issue you pointed out, upon the browser redirecting him back to his view his new `request` object's headers WILL NOT contain the custom header he just set on his `HTTPFound()`.

Comment: @X-Istence: yup, it's clear; I missed that the OP expected headers to be passed on to the view they are redirecting the client to. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way HTTP works, what you are asking is not possible. You can use either GET parameters to pass the data, or you can store the data in a cookie instead.